# pointer query in C style to C++ typecasting

Tags: c++

```
typedef uint8_t RANGE;

int main()
{    
   const  uint16_t  FREQ_RATED_MIN_VALUE = 54;

   RANGE* min;

   min = (uint8_t*)&FREQ_RATED_MIN_VALUE; // C style tyecast

   cout << min << endl; // prints value

   min = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&FREQ_RATED_MIN_VALUE); //ERROR to be removed in this statement to be written in C++ style typecast

   return 0;
}
```

Need help to have the C++ style typecast in the statement commented..

Answer (score 0):

Your cast discards `const` qualification. Casting away constness with C++-style casts requires `const_cast`. Try this:

```
min = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(const_cast<uint16_t*>(&FREQ_RATED_MIN_VALUE));
```

Comment: I mostly like your answer, although I think casting a `uint16*` to a `uint8*` would almost always be the job of `static_cast`.

Comment: @DrewDormann But you can't perform this cast with a static cast. You *can* cast `uint16_t` to `uint8_t` with a static cast, but the OP wants pointers for some reason. The example in the question seems nonsensical, but hopefully they have some valid reason.

Comment: It makes some sense; he wants to alias the `uint16_t` by `uint8_t` (which is a permitted alias)

Comment: @learningfellow consider using `RANGE const *min;` - although your cast is permitted, it causes undefined behaviour if you try to write through it to the const object.